# pl/sql function to parse string to token in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, split

I have written this code

```
Select replace (upper(substr(div_no,1,3), ',' ','',''') 
from dual
```

I want when user write div_no like this `('v0e200,q0e600')` must return

```
v0e,q0e
```

If I have a string like `'s05200 , s02700'` I want to take first three characters, like `'s05 ',' s02'`

Comment: Normally 'token' means to split a delimited string into multiple rows in a result set. Is that what you really want?

Comment: yes i have a string like 's05200 , s02700' i want to take first thre char to be like 's05 , s02' and pase it variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're looking for the `translate()` function :

```
SQL> select translate ('vwe200,qwe600', ',1234567890', ',')
  2  from dual;

TRANSLA
-------
vwe,qwe

SQL>
```

---

So your revised test data clarifies the requirement. Here is a regex solution for extracting the first three characters from each segment of a string:

```
SQL> with testdata as (
  2      select 'vwe200,qwe600' as str from dual union all
  3     select 's05200 , e0300' as str from dual
  4  )
  5  select regexp_replace(str, '([a-z0-9]{3})([a-z0-9]*)(,?)','\1\3')
  6  from testdata; 

REGEXP_REPLACE(STR,'([A-Z0-9]{3})([A-Z0-9]*)(,?)','\1\3')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
vwe,qwe
s05 , e03

SQL>
```

If removing the trailing spaces is required it can be done by adjusting the regex pattern :

```
SQL> with testdata as (
  2      select 'vwe200,qwe600' as str from dual union all
  3     select 's05200 , e0300' as str from dual
  4  )
  5  select regexp_replace(str, '( *)([a-z0-9]{3})([a-z0-9 ]*)(,?)','\2\4')
  6  from testdata; 

REGEXP_REPLACE(STR,'([A-Z0-9]{3})([A-Z0-9]*)(,?)','\1\3')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
vwe,qwe
s05,e03

SQL>
```

---

Injecting additional quotes is a use for the `replace()` function:

```
SQL> select replace('s05 , e03', ',', ''',''') from dual;

REPLACE('S0
-----------
s05 ',' e03

SQL>
```

Use the output from the previous answer as the input for this one.

Comment: no i want to use substr function if div_no like this 's05200 , e0300' TRANSLA not work in this case

Comment: i have another question if i want to take the result and pass it to variable 
for EX v_1 := regexp_replace(str, '([a-z0-9]{3})([a-z0-9]*)(,?)','\1\3') ; 
and then p_1 in (v_1) this write or not ?

Comment: and i want to replace , with ','

Comment: NO both answer is wright but i am new in stackoverflow and i do't know how to accept both answer

Comment: You can't accept two answers. You should accept the better of the two, however you judge that. You can upvote as many answers as you like, as an acknowledgement that more than one answer can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle 12c Query**:

```
with FUNCTION getFirst3CharsOfDelimitedList(
  str IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  val VARCHAR2(4000);
  i   INTEGER := 1;
  occ INTEGER := 1;
BEGIN
  val := SUBSTR( str, i, 3 );
  LOOP
    i := INSTR( str, ',', 1, occ );
    EXIT WHEN i = 0;
    LOOP
      EXIT WHEN SUBSTR( str, i + 1, 1 ) <> ' ';
      i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;
    val := val || ',' || SUBSTR( str, i + 1, 3 );
    occ := occ + 1;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN val;
END getFirst3CharsOfDelimitedList;
testdata as (
  select 'vwe200,qwe600' as str from dual union all
  select 's05200 , e0300' as str from dual
)
SELECT getFirst3CharsOfDelimitedList( str ) FROM testdata;
```

**Output**:

```
GETFIRST3CHARSOFDELIMITEDLIST(STR)
----------------------------------
vwe,qwe
s05,e03
```

Comment: create or replace function en(div_no varchar2) return varchar2
is

v_div_no varchar2(100) ;
v_length varchar2(100) ;

BEGIN
v_length := length(div_no) ;
for i in 1..v_length loop
v_div_no := substr (div_no,1,3)|| substr (div_no,instr(div_no,','),4);
return v_div_no ;
end loop;

END ; 

what should modify to this function ??

Comment: please explain this function

Comment: @mohamedsaied The function I posted just gets the first 3 characters of the string then it iterates finding each comma and gets the following 3 characters (ignoring any leading spaces).

Comment: YES 
I WANT TO UNDER STAND THIS LINE ONLY
EXIT WHEN SUBSTR( str, i + 1, 1 ) <> ' '

Comment: @mohamedsaied You are shouting; that is not necessary. It just exits the inner loop when a non space character is found next.

Comment: Both answer is right and i accepting the both sorry I'm​ new in stack overflow and I don't know how to accept both answer ..